# Add Tomcat deployment restriction

Tags: tomcat

As per the current need, We want to restrict the deployment of one of the application with system variable. Is there are a way in the tomcat config to do so without removing the completed war from the webapps directory.

We have multiple tomcat servers running in out environment. Each server has currently running with 2 applications. With the current need, we want to to the application-2 deployment in some of the server instance. Application-1 has to be deployed in all the instance.

`Tomcat-server -1
     Application-1
     Application-2
Tomcat-server-2
     Application-1
     Application-2
Tomcat-server-3
     Application-1
     Application-2(Stop deployment)`

Note: The deployment should be stopped during the server startup.

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `deployIgnore` attribute of the [Host](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation) element in conjunction with [system property replacement](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/index.html) in XML configuration files. You'll end with something like:

`<Host ... deployIgnore="${deploy.ignore.pattern}>`